# Compute power (of light) received on a mesh

Tags: light

I'm working on an animation of basically a spotlight illuminating an object, with a second object being illuminated only by the light reflected from the first.

Right now it's solely for illustrative purposes, with the technical calculations being done separately. One of those calculations is the amount of light (specifically the number of photons) that actually hit the objects.

So now, I was wondering if there was any way that Blender could output that number, and if that is the case, then how precise would it be?

Answer (score 3):

Blender has no functionality for this.

EEVEE does not calculate anything close to realistic light interactions you might want and Cycles will not give you even remotely accurate caustics - that means any calculations of the amount of light that is refracted or reflected(!) is not very accurate. Light reflected by glossy shaders(or glossy component of shaders) will be quite inaccurate. Fresnel effects for example are considered when calculating the reflected light hitting the camera, but not other objects. It is better to choose some other tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! I was expecting this, but I thought I should ask since Blender already does so many great things.

Comment: There are going to be a lot of improvements in Cycles with Cycles X project that is currently worked on. I heard that caustics rendering is being improved a lot, maybe there is a chance it would be possible in the future.